# App blows up when awaiting non-async operation that is wrapped in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm calling into a 3rd party assembly which doesn't have an async interface, however my code is otherwise async. I have work I can do while waiting for the operation, so I've wrapped it in async to allow for clean calling code.

```
    static Task<string[]> GetRequiredFields(string path)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Aspose.Words.Document doc = null;
            try
            {
                doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(path);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to load doc");
            }

            return doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames();
        });
    }
```

My understand this is the correct way to wrap it. I've omitted the word async from the method name itself to imply to the caller that it isn't in fact truely async.

This works

```
    var thetask = GetRequiredFields(merge.DocxPath);

    var result = thetask.Result;
```

This does not

```
    var thetask = await GetRequiredFields(merge.DocxPath);
```

By 'does not' I mean that it doesn't throw an exception if I wrap it. It just bombs out of the whole application immediately. So I'm not too sure what the inclusion of the async keyword is doing that differs from accessing the result directly.

If I step through the code, I've found that it all breaks on the line where I instantiate the document in the wrapped code. It does not get picked up in the catch. Stepping over the document line is when the debugger detaches and the application exits.

Comment: Is this a Console app?

Comment: Yea it is currently under a console app

Comment: Can you try running VS under administrator rights and see if it fails the same?

Comment: It is running under administrator already I'm afraid

Comment: @DanRevell: Does the Console's `Main` method wait for the asynchronous requests to complete?